# Why is row indexing called twice?

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to give numbers to my rows in ListView.

```
public void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProfile.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWidth.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLength.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPrice.Text))
        return;
    ListViewItem items = listView1.Items.Add((counter++).ToString());
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(items.Text);
    item.SubItems.Add(txtProfile.Text);
    item.SubItems.Add(txtWidth.Text);
    item.SubItems.Add(txtLength.Text);
    item.SubItems.Add(textBoxPrice.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
    txtProfile.Clear();
    txtLength.Clear();
    txtWidth.Clear();
    textBoxPrice.Clear();
}
```

I have problem because every time I hit Add in my WindowForms it add like this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBgVk.png]

Can somebody tell me why is this happening when I am saying that counter starting at 1 is incremented by 1 every time when I click ADD and only once.
Thank you.

Comment: You're calling `listView1.Items.Add()` twice. Remove the `ListViewItem items...` line and replace the line after with `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem((++i).ToString());`

Comment: @41686d6564 Thank you so much. It is working fine now.

Comment: Why not use the count built into the list rather than a separate variable